# Java reattempt execution of service calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am developing an application in Java, Spring which contains a flow on a single button click.
The flow contains two service calls. On the basis of those service calls a decision is made whether to proceed forward or to end the flow.

The services which are involved in this flow are third party APIs. In case there is any network issue or if those APIs are down, this flow will not proceed.

The requirement here is that if there are any of the above problems which don't respond with a result, the service call should be attempted 3 times without repeating the previous service calls if they have already responded.

I would like to know if there is any feature in spring or any other framework which can be used to achieve the above flow.

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: Plenty of frameworks addressing this, e.g [FailSafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) and [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix). Spring probably also contains functionality for it.

Comment: Take a look into http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry. Seems that it will satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Just check out [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) library which is a part of the Spring umbrella of projects (this library is former part of [Spring Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/retry.html), you can look for it in there, depending on how outdated your Spring version is)

You can use `@Retryable` annotation and its `maxAttempts` to implement your requirements

Assuming you have required dependencies([spring-retry](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry), [aspectjrt](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt), [aspectjweaver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver)) in place and use modern Spring version with annotation-based configuration, you need conceptually to implement 3 steps:

**1. Enable Retry support**

add `@EnableRetry` to one of your Spring application's `@Configuration`-marked classes as described [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry)

**2. Create Service Caller**

Here we expect IOException to be thrown in case of network issue (simplified for example purposes). Going further, you can also look into involving pauses between retries by specifying [backoff timeout](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry#java-configuration-for-retry-proxies)

```
@Service
public class ServiceCaller {

    @Retryable(value = IOException.class, maxAttempts = 3)
    public Result callFirstService() throws IOException {
        return actualCallLogicToSomeService(...);
    }

    @Retryable(value= IOException.class, maxAttempts = 3)
    public Result callSecondService() throws IOException {
        return actualCallLogicToSomeAnotherService(...);
    }
```

**3. Perform harness call from outside of Service Caller class**

This is important to perform actual chain of calls to `@Retryable`-marked method outside of declaring class to make underlying aspectj proxies work correctly:

```
@Autowired
private ServiceCaller caller;

public Result doChainOfCalls() throws IOException {
   caller.callFirstService(); //in case of network issue fails after 3 attempts with IOException
   caller.callSecondService(); //after above line passed successfully also attempts 3 times according to @Retryable
   ...
}
```